# Spark sample code not serializable

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark

I ran the sample code from spark tutorial. It works fine before but the second time I run it. It says it's not serializable.
Here is the code

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils

// Load and parse the data file.
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "/home/liushiqi9/spark-1.3.0-src/data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")
// Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))

// Train a RandomForest model.
//  Empty categoricalFeaturesInfo indicates all features are continuous.
val numClasses = 2
val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
val numTrees = 3 // Use more in practice.
val featureSubsetStrategy = "auto" // Let the algorithm choose.
val impurity = "gini"
val maxDepth = 4
val maxBins = 32

val model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo,
  numTrees, featureSubsetStrategy, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)

// Evaluate model on test instances and compute test error
val labelAndPreds = testData.map { point =>
  val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
  (point.label, prediction)
}
val testErr = labelAndPreds.filter(r => r._1 != r._2).count.toDouble / testData.count()
println("Test Error = " + testErr)
println("Learned classification forest model:\n" + model.toDebugString)
```

It's from this Link:[Random Forest](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-ensembles.html#random-forests)

The Logs look like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint] = MapPartitionsRDD[735] at map at MLUtils.scala:98
splits: Array[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint]] = Array(MapPartitionsRDD[736] at randomSplit at <console>:126, MapPartitionsRDD[737] at randomSplit at <console>:126)
trainingData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint] = MapPartitionsRDD[736] at randomSplit at <console>:126
testData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint] = MapPartitionsRDD[737] at randomSplit at <console>:126
numClasses: Int = 2
categoricalFeaturesInfo: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map()
numTrees: Int = 3
featureSubsetStrategy: String = auto
impurity: String = gini
maxDepth: Int = 4
maxBins: Int = 32
model: org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel = 
TreeEnsembleModel classifier with 3 trees

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:293)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:141)
```

I just don't understand why this task was just fine and then it didn't work.
I didn't reinstall my spark or anything.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you copy pasting this into spark console ?

Comment: No I am using zeppelin to do it.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behavior. Did you ever get any satisfaction on this?

Comment: You need to add a closure to it like this: var tmp={****your algorithm} so they can serialize it